# rails and an up/down rating system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

sorry if it's duplicate, I've been looking for something similar before posting, but no success.

So basically I need an up/down rating system ( it's very similar to the one here on stackoverflow ).

I have 6 rateable models, so polymorphic association seem to be the best option.
But since this table will probably hold a solid number of records, won't it take too much time to get the item rating ( `upvotes_count - downvotes_count` )?

I actually though about adding a new row to each and every rateable model, something like `current_rating_value`. So that this value will be changed every time the rating object will be created/destroyed.

Could you please advice, what might be a better option in this case? Extra UPDATE call to change the `current_rating_value` or an extra SELECT(SUM...) call to calculate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how much traffic you get loading these models it could tax resources more then desired. I've ended up using [acts_as_votable](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable) gem in my projects. Its very easy to make a model votable and it also caches the data which is also awesome.

Answer (score 1):

for the long-term performance, you should add something like current_rating_value into every ratable model. Everytime there is new rate, just update this field.

Otherwise, it will be very harmful to performance when you have to calculate the rating everytime.